# How do I change the "label" reported by lsblk?

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I have a USB stick that once-upon-a-time contained Ubuntu installation media.  I have repurposed the device, but the original label has stuck despite my efforts to change it.

`lsblk -o label` reports that the name is *Ubuntu 16.10 amd64* (from prior use).  `lsblk` reports this same label for each of its 4 new partitions, and this label shows up as a mountpoint each time I insert the disk.  This is confusing from many perspectives.

I have tried the following, unsuccessfully:

- changing partition names using parted
- re-partitioning
- new disk label (gpt)
- new UUIDs for disk and partitions
- different computers.

Where is this "label" coming from, and how do I change it?

Comment: With new UEFI systems using gpt there are two labels. Label & partlabel. Label is part of file system and partlabel is part of gpt's data on partition. I try to remember to change when creating partitions with gparted. Otherwise I use Disks (about only thing Disks is good for). to see both:  `lsblk -f -o +partlabel` In disks you can use the gears icon to select edit of labels.

Comment: Fyi, a GPT partition label (partlabel) can be changed from the command line with `sgdisk`.  See `man sgdisk` for details, specifically the `-c` option.

Answer (score 59):

Since the label is a property of the filesystem there are individual ways to set the label for different file systems.

for ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems you use:

```
e2label /dev/XXX <label>
```

for btrfs:

```
btrfs filesystem label /dev/XXX <label>
```

for reiserfs:

```
reiserfstune -l <label> /dev/XXX
```

for jfs:

```
jfs_tune -L <label> /dev/XXX
```

for xfs:

```
xfs_admin -L <label> /dev/XXX
```

for fat/vfat (using dosfstools):

```
fatlabel /dev/XXX <label>
```

OR (using mtools):

```
mlabel -i /dev/XXX ::<label>
```

for exfat (you might need to install `exfat-utils` first):

```
exfatlabel /dev/XXX <label>
```

for ntfs:

```
ntfslabel /dev/XXX <label>
```

for swap (first you need to `swapoff`):

```
swaplabel -L <label> /dev/XXX
```

source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming#by-label

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** *Excellent first answer!*  **+1** Please do take [the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with how this site works as it's something like [the star in the middle of this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OCe3W.png)...  **;-)**

Comment: May I ask how to rename label for iso9660? (I have read, this filesystem of usb or floppy, but this type of fs is not mentioned in the list above

Comment: `btrfs filesystem label /dev/XXX <label>` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The easy way is to start `gparted` and in the top right go to `/dev/XdY`and select the disk you want to edit:

[image]

The options are:

1. right-click the partition you want to rename and click <kbd>Label file system</kbd>

   Then type the name you want the partition to have and press <kbd>OK</kbd>

   Repeat for the other partitions.

   Click the little green check-mark, applying all operations

If that would fail, take option 2:

### This will destroy everything on the USB stick!

2. Go to the menu <kbd>Device</kbd> - <kbd>Create Partition Table</kbd> - <kbd>msdos</kbd>

   This will wipe everything from the USB stick including the partitions with their silly names.

<sub>**Note¹:** If you would want to do this <s>from the command line</s> *the hard way*, use [`parted`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/parted) instead of `gparted`. **;-)**

**Note²:** For an unmounted USB stick, that's all you need, but if you do this on a mounted internal disk, better use [gparted live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)</sub>

Comment: ... or fairly easy via the command line with `tune2fs` for `ext2/ext3/ext4` file systems. (+1 by the way)