# Why do 2 subdirectories appear with different names in different file situations

Tags: files

Regarding 20.04, KDE Plasma.  Subdirectories in question are '/extra' and '/home'.  Both are mounted on their own partitions.

Perhaps 3 years ago, I installed a new hard disk, and during that installation, I appear to have used '/extra2' and '/home2' to copy from source to destination (the new HD).

Why do certain file-operation windows show what appears is the true system names for said locations, and other file-operation windows show '/extra2' or '/home2'?   These names work fine, but I'd like to get to the bottom of this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These look like bookmarks to me, no more. I suppose you can delete them and re-add them in Dolphin.

Comment: In your first screenshot (Thunar) you refer to the directory names, in the second (dolphin) you refer to names of removable devices. I think you have labeled your partitions that way. Let us see the output of `lsblk -f`.

Comment: I'll check out the Thunar / bookmarks point.  

The output of lsblk -f  is too long to post here, sorry.  But it generally matches the output of 'mount' command.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand what's going on, seeing 'extra2' and 'home2'.  @mook765's suggestion about 'lsblk -f' helps alot.  Those are PARTITION LABELS, which I believe are optional and can be designated when creating the partitions.  I thought they were phantom disk mount points, or something such.  Why Dolphin chooses to display them as a 'bookmark' I don't know.  This is not a problem, so, nothing to chase.  Appreciated the assistance.

Addendum:  Here are the specific steps I took to remedy the situation:

sudo cp -n /etc/default/grub  /etc/default/grub.bkup

sudo vi /etc/default/grub

1. disable GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" by adding # at the beginning
2. set GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
3. remove # from the line GRUB_TERMINAL="console" to disable graphical terminal.

sudo update-grub

sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target

(restart system, comes up into console mode, log in as 'root')

(to change the filesystem labels, partitions need to be unmounted)
umount /extra

umount /home

(this removes the '2' from labels '/extra2' and '/home2')

e2label /dev/sdc1 extra

e2label /dev/sdc2 home

mount /extra

mount /home

(check that changes have happened)

lsblk -f

sudo mv /etc/default/grub.bkup /etc/default/grub

sudo update-grub

sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target

shutdown -r now

File manager 'Dolphin' now looks UN-problematic.
Good luck.

Comment: This are not bookmarks. This are partitions which are shown under `Removable Devices`. Dolphin displays a partition label if one exists and will display a name based on partition size if not, most file managers behave this way. Partition labels are optional but very useful when you use a meaningful label like you did. It helps identify partitions,I always label my partitions and also use the labels in `/etc/fstab`. You can always change the labels without unmounting, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103592/590937).